# How do I make the drawing move by default, independent of MouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing

I am modifying a piece of written code, and I want to make the cloud drawing move independently from MouseEvent. The current scenario is this: When I move the mouse, the cloud moves left by 2 pixels. However, I want the cloud to move left 2 pixels by default, without MouseEvent being a part of this. Even though I moved the if else statement out of the method, it still follows the MouseEvent mouseMoved method. "cloudmove" is whatneeds to be modified to move by itself, independent of the mouse.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Plane2 extends JPanel 
{
    boolean bLandingGearOut = false;

    int planex=0;    //a starting x location variant, this will adjust as the mouse moves
    int planey=0;    //a starting y location variant, this currently is just a placeholder for mouse movement in the y plane

    int cloudx=900;
    int cloudy=60;
    int cloudmove=50;
    boolean landingGear = false;

  /*The constructer method sets some things up*/
  public Plane2()
  {      
    PolygonListener listener = new PolygonListener();  //create a polygon listener
    addMouseListener(listener);  //listen for mouse changes 
    addMouseMotionListener(listener);  //listen for mouse movement
    setBackground(Color.blue);   //set the background of the JFrame to blue
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500,750)); //set default size of JFrame window 
  }

  /*This method will be called every time we invoke repaint and it will redraw the graphics window*/


public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
      {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    page.setColor(Color.blue);  //set color for the tires



   //All you need to do is copy this text into your file and change the name of the two arrays
   //If you also copy the last line (page.fillPolygon(xloc_changethisname,yloc....) make sure your
   //Graphics object is called page and make sure you change the 3 array names inside the fillPolygon method 

//********X*********
    int[] xloc_plane = {planex+427,planex+426,planex+333,planex+324,planex+28,planex+30,planex+80,planex+90,planex+375,planex+414,planex+451,planex+456,planex+475,planex+470,planex+477,planex+478,planex+467,planex+405,planex+426};

//********Y*********
    int[] yloc_plane = {planey+87,planey+89,planey+88,planey+81,planey+71,planey+67,planey+58,planey+53,planey+52,planey+39,planey+20,planey+16,planey+20,planey+54,planey+56,planey+66,planey+68,planey+74,planey+86};
    page.setColor(Color.yellow);  //set car color
    page.fillPolygon(xloc_plane,yloc_plane,xloc_plane.length);

    page.setColor(Color.black);  //set color for the window

    int[] xloc_window = {planex+83,planex+98,planex+101,planex+102,planex+102,planex+88,planex+83,planex+84};
    int[] yloc_window = {planey+59,planey+59,planey+59,planey+56,planey+54,planey+54,planey+57,planey+58};
    page.fillPolygon(xloc_window,yloc_window,xloc_window.length);  //this does the actual drawing of the car window   


    page.setColor(Color.blue);  //set color for the tires

    page.fillOval(planex+126,planey+75,16,16); //front tire
    page.fillOval(planex+275,planey+79,16,16); //back tire

       cloudmove-=2;   //every time mouse is moved it will move the cactus 2 pixels to left

        if(bLandingGearOut == true) 
    {
      paintGears(page);
    } 
    else if(bLandingGearOut == false)
    {

    }

       //All you need to do is copy this text into your file and change the name of the two arrays
    //If you also copy the last line (page.fillPolygon(xloc_changethisname,yloc....) make sure your
    //Graphics object is called page and make sure you change the 3 array names inside the fillPolygon method 

    //********X*********
    int[] xloc_cloud = {cloudmove+cloudx+249,cloudmove+cloudx+263,cloudmove+cloudx+269,cloudmove+cloudx+273,cloudmove+cloudx+273,cloudmove+cloudx+266,cloudmove+cloudx+257,cloudmove+cloudx+245,cloudmove+cloudx+234,cloudmove+cloudx+224,cloudmove+cloudx+217,cloudmove+cloudx+215,cloudmove+cloudx+208,cloudmove+cloudx+204,cloudmove+cloudx+192,cloudmove+cloudx+187,cloudmove+cloudx+177,cloudmove+cloudx+173,cloudmove+cloudx+168,cloudmove+cloudx+164,cloudmove+cloudx+157,cloudmove+cloudx+155,cloudmove+cloudx+152,cloudmove+cloudx+146,cloudmove+cloudx+146,cloudmove+cloudx+137,cloudmove+cloudx+125,cloudmove+cloudx+112,cloudmove+cloudx+98,cloudmove+cloudx+82,cloudmove+cloudx+72,cloudmove+cloudx+70,cloudmove+cloudx+56,cloudmove+cloudx+46,cloudmove+cloudx+35,cloudmove+cloudx+25,cloudmove+cloudx+21,cloudmove+cloudx+12,cloudmove+cloudx+12,cloudmove+cloudx+12,cloudmove+cloudx+12,cloudmove+cloudx+17,cloudmove+cloudx+18,cloudmove+cloudx+24,cloudmove+cloudx+30,cloudmove+cloudx+38,cloudmove+cloudx+44,cloudmove+cloudx+51,cloudmove+cloudx+60,cloudmove+cloudx+60,cloudmove+cloudx+62,cloudmove+cloudx+64,cloudmove+cloudx+64,cloudmove+cloudx+75,cloudmove+cloudx+79,cloudmove+cloudx+79,cloudmove+cloudx+82,cloudmove+cloudx+87,cloudmove+cloudx+93,cloudmove+cloudx+102,cloudmove+cloudx+106,cloudmove+cloudx+111,cloudmove+cloudx+121,cloudmove+cloudx+125,cloudmove+cloudx+126,cloudmove+cloudx+128,cloudmove+cloudx+138,cloudmove+cloudx+139,cloudmove+cloudx+146,cloudmove+cloudx+156,cloudmove+cloudx+165,cloudmove+cloudx+171,cloudmove+cloudx+174,cloudmove+cloudx+180,cloudmove+cloudx+189,cloudmove+cloudx+196,cloudmove+cloudx+206,cloudmove+cloudx+215,cloudmove+cloudx+219,cloudmove+cloudx+222,cloudmove+cloudx+227,cloudmove+cloudx+232,cloudmove+cloudx+233,cloudmove+cloudx+235,cloudmove+cloudx+236,cloudmove+cloudx+237,cloudmove+cloudx+239,cloudmove+cloudx+239,cloudmove+cloudx+249,cloudmove+cloudx+254};

    //********Y*********
    int[] yloc_cloud = {cloudy+53,cloudy+61,cloudy+74,cloudy+98,cloudy+113,cloudy+125,cloudy+129,cloudy+138,cloudy+139,cloudy+141,cloudy+139,cloudy+143,cloudy+148,cloudy+152,cloudy+156,cloudy+158,cloudy+159,cloudy+159,cloudy+159,cloudy+158,cloudy+154,cloudy+153,cloudy+151,cloudy+146,cloudy+150,cloudy+152,cloudy+154,cloudy+154,cloudy+154,cloudy+153,cloudy+147,cloudy+145,cloudy+148,cloudy+148,cloudy+142,cloudy+134,cloudy+131,cloudy+120,cloudy+114,cloudy+108,cloudy+103,cloudy+96,cloudy+91,cloudy+83,cloudy+79,cloudy+77,cloudy+72,cloudy+72,cloudy+69,cloudy+69,cloudy+65,cloudy+58,cloudy+56,cloudy+54,cloudy+51,cloudy+49,cloudy+44,cloudy+42,cloudy+39,cloudy+35,cloudy+33,cloudy+33,cloudy+34,cloudy+35,cloudy+35,cloudy+35,cloudy+24,cloudy+14,cloudy+12,cloudy+9,cloudy+4,cloudy+1,cloudy+0,cloudy+0,cloudy+0,cloudy+2,cloudy+5,cloudy+11,cloudy+19,cloudy+20,cloudy+22,cloudy+27,cloudy+32,cloudy+36,cloudy+41,cloudy+45,cloudy+49,cloudy+49,cloudy+54,cloudy+55};


    page.setColor(Color.white);  //set color for the cactus
    page.fillPolygon(xloc_cloud,yloc_cloud,xloc_cloud.length);  //this does the actual drawing of the cactus




  } //end paintComponent
```

This is the full code for paintComponent. The full code for PolygonListener is here:

```
private class PolygonListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
  {   
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){}   //unused event
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){}   //unused event

    //The next method will determine what to do when a mouse button is clicked
    //In this case, a left click will downshift and a rightclick will upshift
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
      if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
      {
        System.out.println("landing gear activated");
        bLandingGearOut = true;
      }
      else if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
      {
        System.out.println("landing gear retracted");
        bLandingGearOut = false;
      }   
      repaint();
    } //end mouseClicked

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}  //unused event
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}   //unused event
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}    //unused event


    //The next method will determine what to do when a mouse is moved
    //In this case that affects the speed and rpms of the car
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) 
    {
//      if (cloudmove+cloudx>2)
//       cloudmove-=2;   //every time mouse is moved it will move the cactus 2 pixels to left
//      else
//       cloudmove=1000;  //resets the location once cactus "drifts" off screen

      System.out.println ("Current Location: "+event.getPoint());  //reports current x|y location on screen

       planex=event.getPoint().x;  //grab the current mouse location and set planex to that location, this will allow the car to move in relation to where the mouse is moving
       planey=event.getPoint().y;
       repaint();  //redraw the image  -  this automatically calls the paintComponent method to redraw the frame    
    } //end mouseMoved


}  //end PolygonListener
```

The main method:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Flyit2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Flying Plane");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Plane2 plane = new Plane2();  
    frame.getContentPane().add(plane);    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The cloudmove integer, as said before, simply does not move the cloud two pixels to the left. Instead, the user is requireed to move the mouse in order for that to work. I want the cloud to move by itself, without the need to rely on the user's mouse movements. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need an event to drive the animation, and that event (obviously) should not be within a MouseListener. The best to use in its place is a Swing Timer, an object that calls an ActionListener repeatedly after a set delay. Check out the appropriate tutorial on this useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the cloud to move by itself, without the need to rely on the user's mouse movements.

The reason the cloud moves is because you invoke repaint() in the MouseListener.

In the painting method you then have:

```
cloudmove-=2;
```

which is executed every time the component is painted.

This code is wrong. The painting method should NEVER update the state of the component. Remove the above statement from the paintComponent() method.

If you want the cloulds to be animated then you need to use a `Swing Timer`. Then when the `Timer` fires the code for the `ActionListener` of your 
`Timer` will be executed. The code for you `ActionListener` would simple be:

```
cloudmove -= 2;
repaint();
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

You can also check out: [Program freezes during Thread.sleep() and with Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816585/program-freezes-during-thread-sleep-and-with-timer/7816604#7816604) for a simple example of using a `Timer`.